# How to style the button with own image? How to remove the white space of the image between the <li> and <li> code?

Tags: jquery, html, image, button, navigation

I want to made a 3-line navigation menu.

This is my fiddle, http://fiddle.jshell.net/ds325/3/

I want to style my button, the original image do not have the grey color background, I want to use my own image.

Beside, why there are white space between my image? How can I remove the white space? So that my image can connect nicely.

my coding

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<button class="menu" ><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkwMp.png" width="40" height="40" /></button>
<div id="navbar" style="display:none;">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
             <div id="wrapper">
             <img src="http://www.weatherclipart.net/free_weather_clipart/umbrellas_page_border_graphic_0515-0908-2220-2617_SMU.jpg" width="35" height="52" class="hover" />
            <p class="text"><a href="#">Home</a></p>
            </div>
            </li>
            <li>
            <div id="wrapper">
             <img src="http://www.weatherclipart.net/free_weather_clipart/umbrellas_page_border_graphic_0515-0908-2220-2617_SMU.jpg" width="35" height="52" class="hover" />
            <p class="text"><a href="#">About</a></p>
            </div>
            </li>
            <li>
            <div id="wrapper">
             <img src="http://www.weatherclipart.net/free_weather_clipart/umbrellas_page_border_graphic_0515-0908-2220-2617_SMU.jpg" width="35" height="52" class="hover" />
            <p class="text"><a href="#">Contact</a></p>
            </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper .text {
position:relative;
bottom:50px;
left:50px;
visibility:hidden;
}

#wrapper:hover .text {
visibility:visible;
}

ul {
    list-style:none;
}
```

Javascript

```
$('.menu').click(function() {
    $('#navbar').toggle('slow');
});
```

If can, please give me a demo, so that it will be more easy for me to understand, thanks.

this is exactly what I want, thanks for helping
http://fiddle.jshell.net/ds325/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use anchor instead of button like following

```
<a class="menu" ><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkwMp.png" width="40" height="40" /></a>
```

Here is the working demo

http://fiddle.jshell.net/ds325/3/

and if you talking about the space between the home link and the image  you can simple update your css as

```
#wrapper .text {
    position:relative;
    bottom: 42px;
    left: 34px;
    visibility:hidden;
    }
```

Updated

Add this to your css

```
#navbar div {
    height: 53px;
}
```

Comment: not the spave between the home link and image, is the space between the home image and about image, is there any problem to solve?
the image should be look like this
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz4nKzGACTZRNk9aR1hZbUtHRU0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: That space is due to your div height inside your li element so you need to adjust that height.For now you can just go with my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the `list-style-image` on your li elements ? Like this :

```
ul li {
    list-style-image: url('path/of/image/file');
}
```

(Sorry but i'm not sure to understand the question if my answer is not what you're waiting for).

Comment: No working, do you see the fiddle? when you click the button, the image will appear, but there are space between the image, I want to remove the space, so that the image can connect smoothly like a straight line.